# Fire object's method in titanium List view

Tags: ios, iphone, listview, titanium

Hi guys i am currently developing for IOS 7 with Titanium SDK 3.2.1.GA and i am in need of help.

I can't find anything on how to call an object's method within a list view

Basically i have a list view with a video player in each cell and a play button on top of it, i want the video player to start playing once the user clicks the play button, but i don't know how to fire the video player's play() method from within the list view.

Thank you for your help in advance

Answer (score 0):

If you posted your code it would be easier to help you, but heres the general idea. Just listen on the `itemClick` event, then fire the play button for that ListItem:

```
// Keep an array of video players or something like that
var vidPlayersRefs = [...,...,...];

listView.addEventListener('itemclick', function(e){
    // Get the video player for that row  
    var videoPlayer = vidPlayersRefs[e.itemIndex];
    videoPlayer.open();
});
```